# How to add user to a folder by calling rest

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to grant a user's account view access directly to a folder by calling the REST API.

The user does not exist on the site, I did google but in many examples I've seen it seems that the users belong to the site already.

Do I have to add the user to the site or to a SharePoint group first?